# android rest template with multi-part request

Tags: android, spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

case 1 : send Entity class as request  [working]

case 2 : send image(multipart) as request [working]

case 3 : send entity + image [not working]

**case 1 :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String add(@RequestBody SampleEntity sampleEntity) {
    return "From Server: " + sampleEntity.getId();
}
```

*test case 1*

```
sampleEntity.setId(123);
String response1 = restTemplate.postForObject(SERVER_URI+"add", sampleEntity, String.class);
System.out.println(response1);
```

Output : From Server: 123

**case 2 :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/imagepart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String imagePart(@RequestPart("image") MultipartFile file) {
    return "From Server(ImagePart): " + file.getOriginalFilename();
}
```

*test case 2*

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> part1 = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    part1.add("image", new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Koala.jpg"));
    String response2 = restTemplate.postForObject(SERVER_URI+"imagepart", part3,  String.class);
    System.out.println(response2);
```

Output : From Server(ImagePart): Koala.jpg

**case 3 :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addimagepart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addPart(
        @RequestPart("sampleEntity") SampleEntity sampleEntity,
        @RequestPart("image") MultipartFile file) {

    return "From Server(Part) : " + sampleEntity.getId() + " "
            + file.getOriginalFilename();

}
```

*test case 3*

```
  sampleEntity.setId(2);
  part.add("sampleEntity",sampleEntity);
  part.add("image", new FileSystemResource("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg"));
  String response2 = restTemplate.postForObject(SERVER_URI+"addimagepart", part, String.class);
    System.out.println(response2);
```

**Error :** this case failed (entity class with image not working)

how to make request Entity + Multipart Request from android rest template to spring mvc server

Comment: did you figure out this problem? I'm facing the same issue as you.. please share your findings

Answer (score 0):

In case 3 the `FormHttpMessageConverter` is used to convert `MultiValueMap` objects for sending in HTTP requests. Unfortunately, default FormHttpMessageConverter does not support conversion of entities to JSON. Thus, You have to add some JSON converter (e.g. `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`) to `FormHttpMessageConverter` manually. Try to use this code:

```
FormHttpMessageConverter converter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
converter.addPartConverter(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, converter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Multipartfile annotation, fetch multipart-data from **request** object

```
if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
            MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;

            Set set = multipartRequest.getFileMap().entrySet();
            Iterator i = set.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
                System.out.println("key :" + me.getKey() + "-"
                        + me.getKey().getClass() + "|||||" + "value :"
                        + me.getValue() + "-" + me.getValue().getClass());
                switch ((String) me.getKey()) {
                case "staffPhoto": {
                    System.out.println("case staffImage "
                            + ((MultipartFile) me.getValue())
                                    .getOriginalFilename());
                    // processImage
                    break;
                }
}
```